# How can I place a form of Subscribe2 plugin in my wordpress blog? (Example: Footer)

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, blogs, subscribe2

I'm stuck with Subscribe2 plugin, I want to place a form for example in footer area of my blog, but plugin's documentation  only talks about placing a form in a "page" using the "[subscribe2]" shortcode.

How can I place a subscribe form in the footer or tab area?

Answer (score 4):

Normally you use shortcodes in the WordPress editor, but if you want to use one directly in your theme files (say, footer.php), use the `do_shortcode` function:

`echo do_shortcode('[subscribe2]');`

Comment: how to use subscribe2 from front end?